# local Simulators for Gas limit

Tags: transactions

How to determine the Gas limits using local Simulators ? I am trying to execute my contract but it showed me a Gas limit hence unable to deploy it to the blockchain

Answer (score 1):

There is a Gas limit for block and gas limit for transaction, so i assume you mean the first one.

The gas limit is the maximum amount of gas, the sender is willing to provide to run its contract, If the gas used exceeds this limit during execution, processing is stopped (for security reasons).

All the IDE provides an estimation of the cost in gas of the contract. Or you could use `eth_estimateGas` which return exactly the amount of gas that the execution would take.

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_estimategas

if you identify the index of your rejected transaction, you can resend it with modified gas limit and gas price (both optional parameters):

```
tx = eth.pendingTransactions[1]
eth.resend(tx, newGasPrice, newGasLimit)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [testrpc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc) to simulate a blockchain. In the terminal window where it runs, it will report the gas used (in hexidecimal) in a given transaction.